# Can we install an above-counter sink (large, about 31" x 18" x5") on a bottom-mount countertop?

Tags: bathroom, sink, mounting

Currently, we have a small oval undermount sink in our bathroom that is roughly 16 by 19.5.  We are thinking bout changing it to a large, rectangular, above-counter sink (13 x 18 x 5) but we obviously have a cut-out in the counter for the undermount.  Can we still use the same countertop?  The new sink already is pre-drilled with a single faucet hole and the drain hole and comes overflow.

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 3):

This will only work if the new sink (including the lip that sits on the counter) is larger than the old sink - it looks like your new sink is actually a bit smaller (13x18 vs 16x19.5) which means there will not be any surface area on the counter for it to rest on.

Lets say for a second you did find a slightly larger sink.  You now need to consider the counter material.  If it is a laminate counter you can easily enlarge the hole for the new sink, however if it is a stone like granite, you will need some specialized tools and know-how in order to enlarge the hole; it could end up being cheaper to just replace it.

You also need to consider how you will remove the old sink.  If the new one is a fair bit larger you can just cut it out, but if margins are tight, you will need to very carefully break the old sink free without damaging the counter.